# Date Operations in Entity Framework Core

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I am using LINQ to talk to Dynamics CRM.  I have found the DbFunctions class in the docs. But when I go to the definition it has NO methods.  I want the DateDiffYear method, but I can find no samples online and it simply does not appear to be present in the reflected code?

Answer (score 1):

OK, the docs are USELESS.  You need to install EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer for this to appear.

Thanks for being my rubber duck again, Stack Overflow!!!!